# Mayavi Animated surface plot

Tags: python, animation, plot, surface, mayavi

I'm using Mayavi to create a surface plot that animates in real time. Currently I'm just making random 2d arrays. The figure only appears when the for loop has completed.

My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
import time

height, width = 360, 640
img = np.asarray(np.random.random((height, width)))

xs = np.linspace(0,width,width)
ys = np.linspace(0,height,height)
x,y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)

z = img

obj = mlab.mesh(x,y,z)

t = time.time()
max_framerate = 10

ms = obj.mlab_source
for i in range(1,50):
    ms.z = np.asarray(np.random.random((width, height)))

    # put a pause in here to control the maximum framerate
    while time.time() - t < (1./max_framerate):
        pass
    t = time.time()

mlab.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

What code editor are you using?
When I run this code in IDLE for Python 2.7 it updates with each iteration, just as you would expect it to. However, I have the problem you describe in Enthought Canopy code editor. I do not know the reason for this.

Comment: I'm using Anaconda 4.1.0 (64-bit). I got it working with different methods now though!

Comment: Hi Samuel, could you show the methods you used please? You can add them as an answer to this question. Thanks